# Make object file not being created

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to write a Makefile since it's a good skill to have and all the times I've worked with them it all just seems like black magic to me.

The Makefile is shall mix C source and unit test in C++. I've looked at some examples and tried reading some guides but I am not getting it to work properly and most examples seems quite simple and doesn't really do what I would like to do.

This is the folder structure:

- project

  - src
  - inc
  - unit_test
  - out

Here is my Makefile so far.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -c -I$(INC_DIR)
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -c -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I$(INC_DIR)

LIBS = -lcppunit

OUT_DIR = out
INC_DIR = inc

CPP_SRCS = $(wildcard unit_test/*.cpp)
CPP_OBJS = $(CPP_SRCS:unit_test/%.cpp=$(OUT_DIR)/%.o)

C_SRCS = $(wildcard src/*.c)
C_OBJS = $(C_SRCS:src/%.c=$(OUTDIR)/%.o)

BIN = $(OUT_DIR)/a.out

.PHONY: all run build clean

test:
    @echo C_SRCS $(C_SRCS)
    @echo C_OBJS $(C_OBJS)
    @echo CPP_SRCS $(CPP_SRCS)
    @echo CPP_OBJS $(CPP_OBJS)

all: run

run: build
    ./$(BIN)

build: $(BIN)

clean:
    rm -f $(CPP_OBJS)
    rm -f $(C_OBJS)
    rm -f $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(C_OBJS) $(CPP_OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(C_OBJS) $(CPP_OBJS) -o $@ $(LIBS)
    @echo "Build successful!"

$(CPP_OBJS): $(OUT_DIR)/%.o: unit_test/%.cpp
    mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)
    @echo Compiling $<
    $(CXX) $< $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@

$(C_OBJS): $(OUT_DIR)/%.o: src/%.c
    @echo Compiling $<
    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

Here is the output of 'make test' which will describe my problem at this point in time.

```
C_SRCS src/add.c
C_OBJS /add.o
CPP_SRCS unit_test/Main.cpp unit_test/Tester.cpp
CPP_OBJS out/Main.o out/Tester.o
```

Why am I not getting the object file **out/add.o** when I am doing exactly the same for the the src folder as for the unit_test folder? What am I missing? It's not that obvious to me.

Comment: Typo: `OUTDIR` instead of `OUT_DIR` in `C_OBJS = $(C_SRCS:src/%.c=$(OUTDIR)/%.o)`

Comment: Wow.... Thanks. I am ashamed that I actually missed that, i've been staring at it for too long.